# Using while(getchar()!='\n') I empty the stdin, but I have to push on Enter key

Tags: c, unix, fgets, enter, getchar

I'm using while(getchar()!='\n')  to empty my stdin, but sometimes if I want to go on, I need to push on Enter key and so the computation continue... Why? I'll post part of my code:

```
while(1){
   if(fgets(buffer,MAX_DIMENSION,stdin)==NULL){ perror("Error"); exit(1);}
   }else{
       printf("Not correct term\n");
       while(getchar()!='\n');
       sleep(1); 
   }
}
```

thanks!

@iharob if i set MAX_DIMENSION=1240 and I send as input: a string > 1024 it remains something on stdin, so I have to use while(getchar()!='\n')

Comment: Why so many people arbitrarily use `while (1)`?... And you don't need to empty anything with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues:

1: Code has extra `}`.

```
//                                                                   here
if(fgets(buffer,MAX_DIMENSION,stdin)==NULL){ perror("Error"); exit(1);}
}else{
// or at the beginning
```

2: Assuming the above it not the issue, then as [@unxnut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805227/2410359) answered, typically `fgets()` contains the `'\n'` and there is no need to *empty* `stdin`.

Yet when the line is excessively long and the `'\n'` is not read by `fgets()`, then is makes sense to read until the end is found.

```
  if (fgets(buffer, MAX_DIMENSION, stdin) == NULL) {
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL) {
    int ch;
    printf("Not correct term\n");
    while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
      ;
    // while(getchar()!='\n');
    sleep(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `fgets` to get a string.  That string was terminated by the newline characters.  Then, you are trying to *empty* `stdin` by using `getchar` and to get something into `getchar`, you have to input another newline character.  You can simply ignore the buffer after `fgets` if that is what you wanted.  There is no need to use `getchar` to empty the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The `fgets()` function, captures the `'\n'` from `stdin`, you are using `getchar()` to extract the `'\n'` from `stdin` but it was already consumed by `fgets()`, that's why you need one extra `\'n'`.

And also, you don't check if `getchar()` returns `EOF` instead of a character. And in my opinion, `while (1)` loops, make it hard to follow the logic

```
char buffer[MAX_DIMENSIONS];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL)
{
   printf("Not correct term\n");
   sleep(1); 
}
```

would be better.

Comment: if i set MAX_DIMENSION=1240 and I send as input: a string > 1024 it remains the remaining part on stdin that it's taken as next input, so I have to use while(getchar()!='\n')

Comment: It would not work, you should then use `while (getchar() != EOF)`, but it would also block, what are you trying to do?